# Retrieving User stats from MAL with a discord bot

Tags: discord.net

I am trying to find a way to retrieve user stats from a given user's "My Anime List" profile and can't figure out how to retrieve the data. I am looking to find their completed, watching, dropped etc from their profile (Found using `MyAnimeList.net/profile/<insert user name here>`).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, when asking a question, try to provide information about exactly what issue you're running into and what you've tried so far. See the community guidelines for asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks. So I can get the website easily enough I am just unsure how to retrieve certain data from the page I get. Each user has stats inside their profile. These are Days watched, mean score, watching, completed, on hold, dropped, plan to watch, total entries, rewatched and episodes.

These are displayed on the front page of their profile and they are the data I am looking to retrieve. I honestly don't know where to start to be able to pull the data and searching online has yielded little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official MyAnimeList API doesn't have any endpoints for getting user profile info. What you *can* do is scrape the webpage.

- Thankfully, MyAnimeList can retrieve XML for user profiles, so it's much easier than parsing HTML. [Here's an example](https://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=domokun1134&status=all&type=anime).
- After retrieving the XML profile, you can parse it in C# using classes/methods in the `System.Xml` namespace, such as `XDocument.Parse()`. There's a lot of resources for help doing that here on StackOverflow.

If you're unsure of how to get this data from the web in the first place, I'd recommend looking into libraries like [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started) or [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/). They abstract a way a lot of the boilerplate for getting info from the web for you so you can just focus on coding. If you want to skip both the XML parsing and web requests altogether, you can let [a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=myanimelist) do it for you.

To keep your Discord.NET bot clean, I'd recommend having a `MyAnimeListService` class that you do this web request/scraping in. You can then inject it into the module you're using for your (I assume) `!anime` command and focus on using the MAL profile data there. This way, you're separating the logic of getting the data from the logic of presenting the data to your Discord users. You can read about dependency injection in Discord.NET [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/commands/commands.html#dependency-injection). Assuming you're using C#, the end result would be accessing the module like this:

```cs
[Group("anime")]
public class AnimeModule : Module
{
    private AnimeModule(MyAnimeListService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }

    private MyAnimeListService Service { get; }

    [Command]
    public async Task AnimeCommand(string username)
    {
        // call your service here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the incredibly late reply, I only just got around to working on it. The Resources you linked were incredibly helpful.